# VRP variant, how to modify provided VRP example

Tags: optaplanner

I'm new to optaplanner and im trying to tweak the VRP example to solve a "similar" problem... but with some differences:

We have a central depot, n customers and a fleet of one or more vehicles.

Each customer has a certain "maximum capacity" (not the same for all of them).

Same for each vehicle.

Initial conditions from the problem include:
"actual capacity" and "desired capacity" for each customer, so that:

actual capacity is >=0 and <=max capacity
desired capacity is >=0 and <=max capacity

"actual depot capacity" is the amount of items available at the depot

We want to REDISTRIBUTE some items so that each customer gets his "desired capacity".

(Tipically most items will be redistributed from one customer to another)

Hard constraints are "maximum capacity"s cannot be excedeed
Soft constraints are vehicle distance (minimize) and difference from "desired capacity" (minimize)

I started by generating a data file for the VRP example with negative customer demand (to simulate desired capacity < actual capacity) but quickly discover that constraint in drl that sums up all customers demands to satisfy vehicle capacity restriction is not what we need here.

¿Do you think that this problem is "similar enough" to worth modifying VRP example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely worth taking the OptaPlanner VRP example (with or without the example GUI) and customizing it to these needs. Start from OptaPlanner 6.0.0.CR1 or better yet CR4 which will be released next week normally. Don't use CR3 because it might have a bug related to shadow variables in VRP.

A) Let's presume `customerDemand = customerDesired - customerActual`. This can be positive (need more items) and negative (need to get rid of items).

Question: How do we validate the Vehicle capacity? We can't just sum it, because it fluctuates from customer to customer. Answer: We use a **shadow variable** (let's call it `freight`) on Customer to calculate how many items the vehicle is transporting from the previous customer to the current. This is very similar to how `arrivalTime` works for the [TimewindowedCustomer](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/domain/timewindowed/VrpTimeWindowedCustomer.java) example. Then use a score constraint rule to verify `freight` on every customer is lower than the vehicle's maximum capacity. And also that `freight` is `>= 0` at every customer.

Now, A) works well if there are plenty of vehicles. Even if there aren't enough items, checking the soft constraint is pointless because it's a fixed constant number (the number of items lacking). You could even decide to spread that shortage fairly over the customers and adjust their `customerDesired` accordingly, before scheduling.

B) However, if there aren't plenty of vehicles, relative to the number of customers, then A) might be insufficient. We 'll want to allow to deliver/pickup less than `customerDemand`, making it more flexible (and therefore complex :). In this case, a Customer has 2 genuine (=non-shadow) planning variables (instead of just 1): the previousStandstill (~ previous customer) and the `deliveryPickup` (`<= demand * 2`).

Comment: Hi Geoffrey!  I've installed optaplanner 6.0.0.CR1 and read documentation about shadow variables.. It really looks like thats the way to go :)  Is there any windowed data file to test? I can see the window enhanced code but no "windowed" data in examples/data folder...

Comment: @alv101 Click on the "import" button. For CR4 there will be one by default

Comment: Due to a bug in the assembly for the zip, CR3 and lower didn't contain any timewindowed datasets. This has been fixed in CR4. The CR4 zip will be available on this Monday.